# Displaying Folium map using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, folium

I would like to display a map in a tkinter GUI I am creating. I currently have a folium map (map1.html) which I would like to be displayed in a tkinter widget.

I have searched quite a lot but could not find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a couple of half baked projects around, but I don't know of any robust way to display html / js in tkinter. You should probably consider electron, eel, or pyhtml (based on QtWebview) instead of tkinter.